# WebRTC vs Asterisk 12 (With secure sockets) : No Audio

Tags: webrtc, asterisk

I am creating a project based on WebRTC and Asterisk. I'm forced tu use HTTPS, WSS, SRTP & DTLS, because new browser don't support non-secure connections ... etc

- Asterisk 12.8.2
- SipJS 0.7.3
- Centos 6.7
- Chrome 48.0.2
- Self-signed certificate (for testing only)
- Secure socket used between browser and Asterisk (wss://149.56.XX.XX:8089/ws)
- Libsrtp (SRTP) & Pjproject installed
- Asterisk server Directly connected to the Internet (Public IP)
- Browser is behinf NAT
- DTLS-SRTP
- WebRTC javascript code located in the same server as Asterisk.

IP's:

- Asterisk IP: 149.56.XX.XX
- Browser Public IP: 67.212.XX.XX
- Browser Local IP: 192.168.0.115

The signaling phase is correct, the peer is well connected to the server.
The aim is to listen to a Playback or Saydigits from Asterisk server. When I run the call, I see that all goes well (SIP and RTP), but no sound in the browser (The volume is up).

I searched on Google, in the forums, but no results .... is that it is a SRTP decryption problem?

Anyone tried this before?

SIP.CONF

```
[1060] 
type=friend
username=1060 
host=dynamic 
secret=lookrtctest
encryption=yes 
avpf=yes
icesupport=yes 
context=outgoing
directmedia=no
transport=ws,wss
force_avp=yes
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
dtlsenable=yes
dtlsverify=fingerprint
dtlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
dtlscafile=/etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
dtlssetup=actpass
nat=yes,force_rport
```

Extensions.conf:

```
[outgoing]
exten => _X.,1,Noop(*** Start Call *** )
exten => _X.,n,Answer()
exten => _X.,n,Playback(vm-from)
exten => _X.,n,SayDigits(123456)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

RTP.conf:

```
[general]
rtpstart=10000
rtpend=20000
icesupport=yes
stunaddr=stun.l.google.com:19302
```

Http.conf:

```
[general]
enabled=yes
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
tlsenable=yes         
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0:8089   
tlsprivatekey=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
```

[RTP traces](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FF8D2noLW2R2F5TGdHLXBtWDg/view?usp=sharing)

[Sip Traces](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FF8D2noLW2cU82S3htaVd1Q2M/view)

[Wireshark traces](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FF8D2noLW2bmZISGI1ZkUzV1U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Finally I know where does the problem. It's on Asterisk side, DTLS Handshake broken (Using Wireshark capture).